# listening to network interfaces on windows phone 8

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, vpn

I am trying to develop a customized vpn app on windows phone 8. Apparently there isn't native support yet, so i m looking for workarounds. I can only see some support for sockets. Is there a way to achieve vpn functionality using lower level network programming on wp8?

Comment: What do you want to do with your VPN? Allow other apps to communicate via it? Or just do some internal corporate magic within your app?

Comment: It will be used so that all internet traffic on the device gets encrypted and routed to corporate servers. It is exclusive to our client's organization.

Comment: That certainly sounds out of the scope for a normal Windows Phone app. It *might* be possible using native code, but there are [very few examples using native code on Windows Phone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/site/search?f[0].Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f[0].Value=C%2B%2B&f[0].Text=C%2B%2B&f[1].Type=Technology&f[1].Value=Native%20Code)

Comment: Is it possible to develop device drivers on Windows phone to do the job?

Comment: You might need to speak to Microsoft/OEMs/Carriers for detail on that

Comment: hmm..seems like a tough gig :)...thanks!